# How to Select different column based on the row value

Tags: mysql, select, row, multiple-columns

Here are my DB column:
sort(1 or 2), head_entry (D or H), vendor_id,invoice_num, line_cost, total_cost

Data will be sorted by invoice_num,sort first. After sorting, for each row in order, 
if head_entry is 'D', select head_entry,vendor_id,invoice_num,total_cost
if head_entry is 'H', select head_entry,line_cost

The output will be written into a txt format file. So the output will be

```
D vendor_id,invoice_num,total_cost 
H line_cost 
H line_cost 
H line_cost 
D vendor_id,invoice_num,total_cost 
H line_cost
```

Any help, much appreciate.

Comment: This is something which is probably best handled in your presentation layer (maybe PHP?).  MySQL is good at generating regular table output, not the sort of output you expect.

Comment: Thank you! Tim...